# Using .htaccess to enable functions main ini has in disable_functions

Tags: php, .htaccess, email, plesk

I have a new account on a Plesk managed server with PHP FastCGI.  The main php.ini for all the accounts has many functions disabled via disable_functions.

In particular mail() and socket related functions are disabled.

I am able to set values via .htaccess but I am unclear on how to re-enable the functions I need and so far I have not succeeded in Googling an answer.

Can someone give an example or direct me to documentation on re-enabling PHP mail() in this situation?

Comment: last I encountered this, I had to ask the provider to change it in a per-virtualhost php.ini file - I don't think these are editable via htaccess or that would kinda defeat the purpose of it (maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: Zathrus you are correct but this host declines to allow a per domain or per vhost specific ini so we moved site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in htaccess.  Only in php.ini: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this
> in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

More over you can do it directly in Plesk GUI as per domain option starting with version 11.0.
Just find for "PHP settings" in domain's hosting settings.

Comment: This host has deliberately disabled that interface in our accounts.

Comment: but which functions you actually need? If only mail() you can create mail account on domain and send mail throw this account.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but the project has already moved servers.  It's a moot question now.  And socket functionality was also required.